# History goBack when accessing route directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

In my react app I have protected routes such as /admin.
If a user accesses this route who does not have permissions to view the page I replace the route with a /forbidden route.

From the forbidden page the user can press a back button which works fine, if the request came from in app routing.

What can I do if a user accesses this route directly over the browser?
I want the user to return to the start page but currently he gets redirected to my oidc providers page.

Comment: You can test that in the history the last page url is part of your app, otherwise redirect to the start?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to get the browser history in react-router

Comment: actually I already tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location but lastLocation returns '/admin' which is wrong because I replaced the route instead of pushing it. Redirecting to /admin would not make any sense because the user would be redirected to /forbidden again

Comment: You need to set appropriate fallback/default routes in case permission to that route is denied. Overriding browser behavior is not a good idea. May be provide a link on the forbidden page to take him to start or OIDC page.
Please share react router version and routes code for more helpful responses